# Is there any module that can show whoever edits a node?

Tags: nodes

Is there any module that can show whoever edits a node, just like how happens on Stack Exchange sites, where the user who edited a post is shown together the author of that post?

Comment: I am thinking that you can use the core tracker module and views to do this. But I am still trying to figure out exactly where to get it to identify the last user to update the node. It might require a CCK module extension or the advanced tracker module or an extended views module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article should be able to help you: [Adding 'Last edited by name some time ago' information](http://11heavens.com/adding-last-edited-by-name-some-time-ago-info-to-node)

I'm not sure how you want it to look exactly, but with a preprocess function and a simple template edit, you can add an editors information.  You can style this however you like and add/remove information, but to show the editor's name and the edit date/time do the following:

Add to template.php (or add the code to the preprocess_node function if already exists):

```
function neuco_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  $editor = user_load($variables['revision_uid']);
  $variables['edited'] = 'Edited by ' . theme('username', $editor) . ' on ' . format_date($node->changed, 'medium');
}
```

In your tpl file (node.tpl.php, node-YOURTYPE.tpl.php, etc):

```
<?php print $edited; ?>
```

Functions used: [`template_preprocess_node()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_node/6), [`user_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_load/6), [`format_date()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/format_date/6), [`theme_username()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_username/6)

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the [Diff](https://www.drupal.org/project/diff) module, or any revision module.

Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... adds a tab for sufficiently permissioned users. The tab shows all revisions like standard Drupal but it also allows pretty viewing of all added/changed/deleted words between revisions.

Comment: What the OP is looking for is a module that shows who is the last user who edited a node when showing the node itself.